# What constitutes a directive in C++, and how can I use them effectively?

Tags: c++

How do you exactly define a directive in programming?

`#include` is a directive, and `using namespace std` is a directive as well, assuming that I  am correct.

What actually makes a sentence or word a directive?

I tried reading from different sources, but all lead to no avail. I  am new to programming and I hope to grasp a good understanding of a directive.

Comment: _" #Include is a directive and using namespace std is a directive as well"_ Nope! That's wrong. Who taught you so??

Comment: [read this](https://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/), usually try to avoid `#define` if you can...

Comment: What would having a detailed definition of a directive allow you to accomplish that you cannot do now?

Comment: Please don't write normal sentences in all upper-case. It's considered *shouting*, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: it is what i read from an online book or maybe i misunderstood which brings me back to my question

Comment: if that is the case then please explain it to me

Comment: thank you all for your swift help and correction and i am sorry for "shouting" i did not know about it.I am happy i joined stack overflow

Comment: For future questions, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if applicable, please learn how to create a [mre]. And of course how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned two different programming constructs in your question: 1) the `#include` [pre-processing directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor#Directives) and 2) the `using namespace` [directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

Each of these constructs is literally referred to as a "directive" in the documentation, but they are completely different things. I can see how that could cause confusion.

Both the pre-processing directives and the using directive are not something that the user gets to define. They have a fixed meaning in the language. They can be used with different arguments to achieve different results.

Directives like `#include` can be used to direct what source code is used in the compilation. For example, `#include <iostream>` will cause the file `iostream` to be included. There are numerous other pre-processor directives, but for starting out, `#include` is by far the most important.

A directive like `using std::cout` instructs the compiler to bring the `std::cout` symbol into the current namespace so it can be referenced as simply `cout`.

I hope this helps clear up the confusion.

Comment: `using std::cout;` is (confusingly, again) not a _using-directive_, but a _using-declaration_. Using-directives are always of the form `using namespace X;`. These are distinct grammar constructs that just happen to share the same keyword `using` to introduce them and happen to be vaguely related in affecting lookup.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I initially had `using namespace std` as the example and then decided that probably wasn't the best idea.

Answer (score 5):

The word "*directive*" is just a normal word from the English language and used with its usual meaning in different contexts without an overarching technical meaning for programming languages or even C++ specifically.

In C++ it is used for two completely separate things:

- *preprocessing directives*, which are constructs introduced by `#` at the beginning (after whitespace) of a source code line and give the preprocessor certain instructions, e.g. `#include`,`#define`, etc. Since C++20 this also includes lines beginning with the tokens `module`, `import` or `export`, used to implement the C++20 module semantics.
- *using-directives*, i.e. statements of the form `using namespace X;` where `X` is the name of a namespace, which is used to make declarations from a namespace visible in another scope.

There is no unifying meaning here. They are not related. It is just a convenient word to use for these constructs with the usual English meaning similar to "*instruction*" or "*order*", literally referring to something that *directs* someone (e.g. the compiler) to (do) something.

Comment: Good answer, you concisely honed in on the misunderstanding.